# Is it possible to run World of Warcaft: Cataclysm inside a VMware Workstation / Player VM?

Tags: vmware-player, gaming

I was just thinking about this. Is it possible to play World of Warcraft in a VMware VM? I know they have made many leaps and bounds in there consumer VM software in the last few years. Anyone know if it can be done? If so is it any good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it as the speed will be highly reduced by the hypervisor I recommend doing it on metal HW if at all possible

Comment: Yeah I currently run WoW on my Windows 7 box, I just wonder about things list this... Maybe one day I guess.

Comment: It is possible, it will be very slow though.